# Flutter, How to Replace Html tags to Text?

Tags: html, flutter

When I am fetching data from the internet I get for example
`<p> Shawarma </p>`,
How can I display the data without appearing the `<p>` tag?
Note that there is a package called: html_character_entities and others but how can I use them in the builder?

```
           FutureBuilder<Iterable<SubCategories>>(
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    return ListView.builder(
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                          Text(
                            snapshot.data!.elementAt(index).description,
                          ),
                    );
                }),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for a package for this ...

```
  FutureBuilder<Iterable<SubCategories>>(
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    return ListView.builder(
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                          Text(
                            snapshot.data!.elementAt(index).description.replaceAll(RegExp(r'<[^>]*>|&[^;]+;'), ''),
                          ),
                    );
                }),
```

Comment: Thank you so much! 
May I ask you did you know that `<[^>]*>|&[^;]+;` defines `<p> </p>` ?

Comment: Please! This does not define only <p> or </p> tags but all html tags can be detected by this expression

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package  : https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html  it will render hrml tags. OR
you can
use this function by creating self :

```
static String stripHtml(String text) {
  return text.replaceAll(RegExp(r'<[^>]*>|&[^;]+;'), ' ');
}
```

In you code you can use like this by using that fucntion:

```
FutureBuilder<Iterable<SubCategories>>(
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                      Text(
                        stripHtml (snapshot.data!.elementAt(index).description,),
                      ),
                );
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [html](https://pub.dev/packages/html) package like this:

```
String _removeHtmlTag(String str) {
    String result = '';
    final document = parse(str);
    if (document.body != null) {
      result = parse(document.body!.text).documentElement!.text;
    }
    return result;
  }
```

and use this like this:

```
print("result = ${_removeHtmlTag('<p> Shawarma </p>')}"); //result = Shawarma
```